# Java, односвязный список

Tags: java, замена, односвязный-список

Недавно начал изучать Java; помогите пожалуйста разобраться почему вылетает NPE?

Пытаюсь удалить узел в односвязном списке по значению.

```
public boolean delElementByValue(E value) {
    Node<E> resultNode = firstNode;
    while (resultNode != null) {
        //NullPointerException в следующей строке
        if (resultNode.getNodeValue().equals(value)) {
            resultNode.getPrevNode().setNextNode(resultNode.getNextNode());
            return true;
        }
        resultNode = resultNode.getNextNode();
    }
    return false;
}
```

Класс Node:

```
class Node<E> {
    private Node<E> prevNode;
    private Node<E> nextNode;
    private E nodeValue;

    Node(Node<E> prevNode, Node<E> nextNode, E nodeValue) {
        this.prevNode = prevNode;
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
        this.nodeValue = nodeValue;
    }

    public void setNodeValue(E nodeValue) {
        this.nodeValue = nodeValue;
    }

    public void setPrevNode(Node<E> prevNode) {
        this.prevNode = prevNode;
    }

    public void setNextNode(Node<E> nextNode) {
        this.nextNode = nextNode;
    }

    public Node<E> getPrevNode() {
        return prevNode;
    }

    public Node<E> getNextNode() {
        return nextNode;
    }

    public E getNodeValue() {
        return nodeValue;
    }
}
```

Смотрел в отладке, цикл проходит 4 итерации и падает, в то время как value стоит на 10+ позиции.

Что-то мне подсказывает, что ошибка какая-то "детская", но догнать уже долгое время не могу.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Покажите, как вы создаёте список?

Comment: Вы были правы, среди значений списка был null, и вызов equals крашил программу.
Спасибо, а то я бы еще час сидел тупил.)

Comment: бывает, но у вас на самом деле есть ещё косяк, следующему за удаляемым элементу, надо присвоить правильный prevNode

Comment: Действительно, забыл.Исправил, благодарю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы удаляете `Node`, тогда метод `resultNode.getNodeValue()` будет возвращать `null`, а у него в свою очередь нет метода `equals`. Попытка его вызова вернет `NullPointerException`.

После того, как вы удаляете `Node`, текущую `Node` нужно смещать на следующую `Node`, а не оставлять на удаленной.

```
resultNode = resultNode.getNextNode();
```

Comment: То ли я тупой, то ли лыжи не едут, зачем смещать на следующую, если происходит выход? Мне кажется он просто в одно из nodeValue засунул значение null

Comment: Точно, так оно и было)

Comment: @Kirsten мог null проинициализировать это поле